# change desktop file manager

Tags: filemanager

I have marlin set to my default file explorer , but when I open my desktop icons it still uses nautilus.

Is there a way to make marlin manage the desktop instead of nautilus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an only way to fix this:
- Marlin should be able to draw the desktop
- Modify mimetypes in /usr/share/applications/defaults.list to call marlin instead of nautilus

Marlin won't be drawing the desktop as it's a file manager and not a
desktop drawer

BTW Elementary OS team has forked Marlin in a project known as Pantheon Files you can also check that out. Hope this helps

Comment: that worked a charm, thanks heaps for the quick response , sorry I took so long to get around to this